# Tkinter Gui Not running when .py file is opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm working on this project and I deiced to add a GUI interface. I have chosen to work with Tkinter cause I'm some sort familiar with Python. I'm running into the problem where I can run the GUI out of visual studio but I am unable to run the GUI off straight of my desktop. I have checked and there are no errors in my code. Can someone please help me fix the code.

This Is a snippet of the code which I am using to run the GUI

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

import os
import shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import getpass
import time

window = Tk()
window.title("Move Files")
window.geometry('546x500')

def Movie():
    TextBox.delete('1.0',END)
    bar['value'] = 0
    messagebox.showinfo('Message title', 'Message content')

def TVShow():
    TextBox.delete('1.0',END)
    bar['value'] = 0
    TVShowMove()

#Buttons
Movie = Button(window,text='Move Movies', command=Movie, padx=50, pady=30)
Movie.place(x=40, y=40)
TVShow = Button(window,text='Move TV Shows', command=TVShow, padx=48, pady=30)
TVShow.place(x=300, y=40)

#Progressbar
bar = Progressbar(window, length=446, style='black.Horizontal.TProgressbar')
bar.place(x=40, y=140)

#TextBox
TextBox = Text(window, height=10, width=55)
TextBox.pack()
TextBox.place(x=40, y=170)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code runs just fine. Are you trying to run the .py file when you double click it on your desktop?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to double click and run it off my desktop.

Comment: And are you on Windows 10?

Comment: Yes i am running windows 10

Comment: I'm not a Windows guy *at all* but what you need to do is create a shortcut to your .py file and have it open with python.exe or whatever it is.

Comment: i have tried to do so but I keep running into the problem of the Command line closing after a second of being opened

Answer (score 0):

code is ok 
i got this problem too!
try to open it from vscode itself

Comment: I can do so and it works but I am trying to run the file without vscode. Is there any way I can do this.

Comment: try cmd I do so

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.8 you cant import any of these.

```
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Instead, you have to import Tkinter as tk as seen below

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
```

Comment: `import tkinter as tk` is enough.  Avoid using `from tkinter import *`.  And the first three import statements are valid in Python 3.8.